# VBA Copy normal range to bottom of table (not same no. of columns)

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new on VBA. I am trying to copy some columns from a range to bottom of a table, they are not in the same columns size, not in the same column order, different in data dimensions too.

The source range looks like (normal excel range A1:C4):

| Date | Product1 | Product2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/02/2022 | 11 | 13 |
| 02/02/2022 | 10 | 11 |
| 03/02/2022 | 12 | 12 |

The destination table looks like (Table1):

| Product | Date | sales no. | sales amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| existing data | existing data | existing data | existing data |
| existing data | existing data | existing data | existing data |
| existing data | existing data | existing data | existing data |

I am trying to copy sales amount from source range to the bottom of Table1. Copy data should be date, sales amount and repeat product type:

| Product | Date | sales no. | sales amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| existing data | existing data | existing data | existing data |
| existing data | existing data | existing data | existing data |
| existing data | existing data | existing data | existing data |
| Product1 | 01/02/2022 |  | 11 |
| Product1 | 02/02/2022 |  | 10 |
| Product1 | 03/02/2022 |  | 12 |
| Product2 | 01/02/2022 |  | 13 |
| Product2 | 02/02/2022 |  | 11 |
| Product2 | 03/02/2022 |  | 12 |

I did try to this nice (short) script. It run smoothly and fast but for 1 column only.

```
Set newrow = ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add()
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & ActiveSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row).Copy
newrow.Range.Cells(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Is there any ideal of nice (short) script to do this for the whole copying columns? Really appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I can only do this by repeating copy column by column with this bulky script, and repeating many rounds for many products in normal range (A1:C4)

```
With ActiveSheet.Listobjects("Table1")
Set newrow = .ListRows.Add()

'1st round
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & ActiveSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row).Copy
newrow.Range.Cells(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B" & ActiveSheet.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row).Copy
.HeaderRowRange.Find("sales amount").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
.HeaderRowRange.Find("Product").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "Product1"
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).FillDown

'2nd round
Set newrow = .ListRows.Add()
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & ActiveSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row).Copy
newrow.Range.Cells(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C" & ActiveSheet.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row).Copy
.HeaderRowRange.Find("sales amount").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
.HeaderRowRange.Find("Product").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "Product2"
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).FillDown
End With
```

Very welcome new ideal or making script more neat and more powerful.
Thank you.